# Mock a logger defined in the constructor using pytest

Tags: python-3.x, logging, constructor, mocking, pytest

I have this class defined:

```
class User():

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger('user.log')

    def get_data(self):
        _data = {
            'username': 'abc'
        }
        _payload = json.dumps(_data)
        self.logger.info("Loaded payload")
        return _payload
```

The test case written for get_data():

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.file_user.Logger')
def test_get_data(self,mock_logger):
    assert User().get_data() == "'username': 'abc'"
    mock_logger.info.assert_called_once_with(
        'Loaded payload')
```

The mocking here fails giving the assertion error "Expected 'info' to be called once. Called 0 times."

Comment: What you're seeing is why creating instances of collaborators in the constructor is a bad idea - `User` is now coupled to the concrete `Logger`. You could decouple by having the logger passed in as a parameter, rather than created by `User` itself.

Comment: I totally agree, but my use-case here demands this. Is there any way I can get the written test to pass?

Comment: what’s mock_info? your function mocks the logger with the name mock_logger. is this a typo or have you omitted some code?

Comment: It is a typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: you're not calling `mock_logger` with those arguments but instead the `info` method on the `mock_logger`. hopefully this hint should be enough for you to figure it out on your own.

Comment: you should read up what a `Mock` object returns when it is initialized, that is why your code is not working, you're close to getting it but you need to understand what `Mock` objects return when initialized, here's a hint, it's not the object itself...

Answer (score 0):

`Logger` is a class, `self.logger.info()` is an instance method. So you need to get the instance of `mock_logger` via `.return_value`.

E.g.

`logger.py`:

```
class Logger():
    def __init__(self, filepath) -> None:
        pass

    def info(message):
        print(message)
```

`user.py`:

```py
import json
from logger import Logger


class User():

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger('user.log')

    def get_data(self):
        _data = {
            'username': 'abc'
        }
        _payload = json.dumps(_data)
        self.logger.info("Loaded payload")
        return _payload
```

`test_user.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from user import User


class TestUesr(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('user.Logger')
    def test_get_data(self, mock_logger):
        mock_logger_instance = mock_logger.return_value
        user = User()
        actual = user.get_data()
        self.assertEqual(actual, '{"username": "abc"}')
        mock_logger_instance.info.assert_called_once_with('Loaded payload')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
 ⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66366372/test_user.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66366372/logger.py          5      2    60%   3, 6
src/stackoverflow/66366372/test_user.py      13      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/66366372/user.py           10      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        28      2    93%
```